# More Songs for Rock Band 4

Tags: xbox-one, rock-band-4

Are the 65 songs that the game comes with the only songs you get without buying more or do you unlock more songs by playing through the single player mode/tour?

Comment: Pretty sure I had read that all songs are unlocked, and that's how RB has run their game before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rock Band's setlist is completely unlocked at purchase. You may choose however, also re-download your old DLC from all other Rock Bands at no additional cost to you.

Comment: its just a *PITA* due to the licensing issues...

Comment: This appears to be correct so I'll accept it. It is rather disappointing that there is nothing else that can be unlocked by play rather than paying for it.

Comment: @JeffS yeah, but it does have quite a list. Guitar Hero's option is a little better but its a double-edged sword. You can play ANY song you want given you have the *PLAYS* for it. Microtransactions, man....worse than DLC. But they do allow the F2P model to work by doing a "TV" where you can jump in and jump out of songs at will.